# cocos2dx 3.13 - DrawNode with animation

Tags: animation, draw, cocos2d-x-3.x

I am a newbie in cocos2d-x 3.13, I want draw with animation in the DrawNode like video: [Art Gurus](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h7925cjqnguvwsb/VID_20160913_104221.mp4?dl=0). It will draw a line the same when draw by hand. Any suggest for this solutions ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In openFrameworks, you could do that with [ofPath](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofPath/). AFAIK, Cocos2dx has no such class, so you would need to create your own.